# Run With Elevated Priv

Tags: 2007, permissions, runwithelevatedprivileges

Will RWEP add a file to a folder it has "Read" permissions for know sharepoint groups (but no sharepoint\system group added)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the REWP operates under the application pool account so there is not restriction in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the system account don't need to be added (even if the folder permissions has no one in it. or has some groups with read only permissions) to the folder or doc lib.